# verificação de < e > em php

Tags: php

Bom tenho que fazer uma verificação de 3 variáveis, com a seguinte regra.

Variáveis:

```
$curva_a
$curva_b
$curva_c
```

Regras:

A variável `$curva_a` sempre tem que ser maior que as outras.
A variável `$curva_b` tem que ser menor que a `$curva_a` e maior que a `$curva_c`.
A variável `$curva_c` sempre tem que ser menor que as outras.

Eu fiz o código em php, porém não gostei muito, ele esta funcionando, mas acho que tem alguma forma melhor de fazer isso.

Segue o código:

```
$erro =  false;

// Verifica os valores das curvas
if (($curva_a < $curva_b) || ($curva_a < $curva_c)) {
    $erro = true;
}
if (($curva_c > $curva_a) || ($curva_b < $curva_c)) {
    $erro = true;
}
if ($curva_c > $curva_a) {
    $erro = true;
}

// Verifica erro
if ($erro === true) {

    echo "erro";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se a sua intenção é comparar três valores, sendo que a ordem final deve ser sempre a mesma:

```
$curva_a > $curva_b > $curva_c
```

Você pode apenas comparar os valores adjascentes:

```
if ($curva_a <= $curva_b) // Erro!
if ($curva_b <= $curva_c) // Erro!
```

> Garantir que `$curva_a` é maior que `$curva_b` e que `$curva_b` é maior que `$curva_c`, já garante que `$curva_a` é maior que `$curva_c` e, portanto, todas as condições são satisfeitas.

Ou ainda, para facilitar, juntar as expressões:

```
if ($curva_a <= $curva_b || $curva_b <= $curva_c) {
    // Erro!
}
```

Para testar, eu fiz um pequeno código:

```
// [[$a, $b, $c], $expected]
$tests = [
  [[1, 2, 3], false], // a < b < c, erro!
  [[1, 3, 2], false], // a < b > c, erro!
  [[2, 1, 3], false], // a > b < c, erro!
  [[3, 2, 1], true],  // a > b > c, ok!
  [[1, 1, 1], false], // a = b = c, erro!
  [[2, 2, 1], false], // a = b > c, erro!
  [[2, 1, 1], false], // a > b = c, erro!
  [[2, 1, 2], false]  // a > b < c, erro!
];

foreach($tests as $i => $test)
{
  list($curva_a, $curva_b, $curva_c) = $test[0];
  $expected = $test[1];

  assert(($curva_a <= $curva_b || $curva_b <= $curva_c) == !$expected, "Erro no teste {$i}");
}
```

Se todos os testes passarem, nenhuma saída é produzida. Porém, ao se alterar o segundo valor em `$tests`, referente ao resultado esperado, `$expected`, um erro de `assert` será disparado para aquele teste.

Veja em funcionamento no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/GgFt), ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/DycDnU).

Comment: if( ! ($curva_a > $curva_b > $curva_c) ){ /*errou*/ }
Já resolveria não acha ?

Comment: @BartolomeuS.Gusella, o PHP não suporta este tipo de sintaxe.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar uma verificação apenas de `$curva_a` com `$curva_b` e `$curva_b` com `$curva_c`

```
if(!($curva_a > $curva_b && $curva_b > $curva_c) ){
 /*ERRO*/ 
}
```